# Java test gradebook

Tags: java

I'm currently trying to create a java application that creates an array to store 20 test grades from random numbers between 0-100. Then I want to calc/print the highest/average score. This is what I have so far but I keep getting errors. Any help?

```
  import java.util.Random;

    public class ComputerGrades 
    {
         public static void main(String[] args)
         {

            Random r = new Random();
            int total = 0;


             int[] studentGrades = new int[20]; 


             for ( int i=0; i<20; i++ )
             {
                studentGrades[i] = r.NextInt();

                 System.out.printf("%d", studentGrades[i]);

                total+= studentGrades[i];

             }
            int max = studentGrades[0];
            for ( int i=1; i<20; i++ )
             {
                if(studentGrades[i] > max)
                    max=studentGrades[i];
            }


    System.out.printf("\nThe average is %d", total/20);
    System.out.printf("\nThe highest grades is %d", max);

         }
    }
```

Comment: What are the errors ?

Comment: One error is: NextInt not exists. It's nextInt

Comment: And while not an error, you may want to move the `max` calculation into the same for loop where you're assigning grades to avoid having to loop twice.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `nextInt`, supply a maximum of 101 (as the result is 0 inclusive, maximum exclusive):

```
studentGrades[i] = r.nextInt(101); // will be a number from 1 - 100
```

Also, divide by array length, not a "magic number". If you want to go further, use doubles for decimal places on the average:

```
System.out.printf("\nThe average is %.2f", (double) total/(double) studentGrades.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final int SIZE = 20;
int[] grades = new int[SIZE];

for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) grades[i] = Math.random() * 101;
```

Then find the highest and average scores of the elements of array grades.